# Comparison of two values from two list

Tags: linux, shell-script, shell, files, iptables

I am trying to compare two strings. One value is coming from `iptables` and the other is from a file where I saved previous records.

I want to identify if there is a new user appear in iptables. If so I will add that record to my file.

Here what I have tried so far.

```
chain=$(/usr/sbin/iptables -vnL | grep "references" | awk '{print $2}')

file=/data/..../2011-11.txt


for i in $chain
do
         while IFS=',' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5
         do
              user=$f1

              if [ $i == "$user" ]; then
                  echo "user matched $user"
              elif [ $i != $user ]; then      #a new user
                  echo "new user $i"
                  break
              fi   #user matching if     

         done < "$file"

done    #reading data from the file for loop
```

My iptables looks like (chain)

```
NalindaChainksSdt
KasunikaChainyCehf
KivinduChainmzWeN
KumudikaChainsXcAp
LocalServerChainRyqvv
```

File values are (file)

```
NalindaChainksSdt
KasunikaChainyCehf
```

Here script should ignore `NalindaChainksSdt` and `KasunikaChainyCehf` names from chains. (user matched)

But this does not do the trick. It just identify all users in the file as new users.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you give the content examples of $chain and $file variables?

Comment: @EgorVasilyev Yes, question was edited and add some samples.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, it never makes sense to say

```
if condition; then
    do something
elif condition is false; then
    do something different
fi
```

Because, if *`condition`* isn’t true, then you know that it’s false. 
You can just say

```
if condition; then
    do something
else
    do something different
fi
```

Now think about the logic of your script. 
It’s an *n*<sup>2</sup> algorithm — or, to be more precise,
if `$chain` is *m* words long, and the file is *n* lines long,
then the code can potentially loop *m*×*n* times. 
Now think about what that means for your problem:

You’re saying that `$i` is a new user
if you find *any* user (`$user`) in the file that’s different. 
But `$i` is a new user only
if ***every*** user in the file is different from `$i`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to do, if user from chain and file matched, then need to exit from that comparison and goes to the next user from chain.

Answer (score 1):

I can offer the simpliest solution with `comm` util:

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/sbin/iptables -vnL | grep "references" | awk '{print $2}' > /tmp/chain

chain="/tmp/chain"
file="full path to 2011-11.txt"

comm -13 "$file" "$chain"
```

If `2011-11.txt` contains:

```
NalindaChainksSdt
KasunikaChainyCehf
```

And `chain` contains:

```
NalindaChainksSdt
KasunikaChainyCehf
KivinduChainmzWeN
KumudikaChainsXcAp
LocalServerChainRyqvv
```

Then **output will be**:

```
KivinduChainmzWeN
KumudikaChainsXcAp
LocalServerChainRyqvv
```

Comment: I tried, but no luck.

Comment: @Sachith, what problems did you get?

Comment: Nothing is happening. Can you give me a working example.

Comment: @Sachith, you need to replace `full path to 2011-11.txt` to real file path. i edited my answer to remove relative file path. Execute it again.

Comment: `comm: : No such file or directory`

Comment: @Sachith, show me please `chain` and `file` variables. What filepath did you define to each variable?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68523/discussion-between-sachith-and-egor-vasilyev).